# Survey analysis - quantifying individual component effects on the overall measure

Tags: survey

I'm pretty new to the survey analysis / stats world but wanted to get some ideas if what I want to do is possible - example below:

In my survey, we ask 3 different satisfaction question (say A, B, C).

The overall measure that I calculate is the proportion of people who satisfied on all (e.g. satisfied on A, B AND C).

Is there a way or stats technique to quantify how much satisfaction on B contribute to the overall measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fit the following two-by-two table:

$$ \begin{array}{c|cc}
& \text{Satisfied with all} & \text{Dissatisfied with at least one} & \\ \hline
\text{Satisfied with B} & n_{11} & n_{12} \\
\text{Dissatisfied with B} & n_{21} & n_{22} \\
\end{array}$$

and consider pretty much any binary analysis of data. I would think that Cohen's Kappa, a measure of agreement, could be a useful measure: does knowing satisfaction with B pretty much tell us whether they're satisfied with all measures?

Comment: Thanks AdamO - will look at Cohen's Kappa as you suggested. On the two-by-to table, can I just confirm that by definition, n21 will be 0? Would this have an effect?

Comment: @woiya yes it would be zero. You could relevel the response as satisfied with A and C alternately.